# Chrome reports my answer as a Phishing site

Tags: support, google-chrome

Only when using the direct link to the answer. Other answers or just linking to the question don't raise the warning:

[php mysql_connect Warning disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16912899/php-mysql-connect-warning-disable/16913444#16913444)

Appreciate this is likely out of the devs control but thought it would be of interest.

[image]

Comment: See that "Report an error" in your screenshot? May be you should go *there*.

Comment: Can't reproduce this myself in Chrome (Win7).

Comment: Seems similar to some of the Antivirus software kicking in on harmless code sections within a question. There probably is something within a post tripping it up when it can safely ignore it.

Comment: Strangely, browsing in incognito mode doesn't give the warning.

Comment: Retagged as support, as this is not a Stack Exchange bug, but a Chrome one.

Comment: Are you getting this for some other sites as well?? 
If so, consider updating chrome and check your sys-date.

Comment: @007 - I and other devs have reproduced for this particular question. If we could find _other_ questions that show this, we may have something to go on.

Comment: @007 not seeing this on any other sites. Chrome auto updates itself and so naturally running the latest version. Sys date is fine. Unlikely to be anything specific to me as others have reproduced.

Comment: http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/static/submit_success.html?hl=en-US

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate because that one is no longer reproducible, indicating the two are different problems.